# Server Password changed for email on s3, unable to sign in, connection error

Tags: email, samsung-galaxy-s-3

My email worked fine on Galaxy S 3 for 3 weeks, but all of a sudden I receive a message saying "Server Password changed, sign in failed connection error". I have changed nothing and was still receiving emails minutes before this happened. Also, the same password still works when logging into Virgin Media to see email online.

Comment: Did you enable 2 Step authentication for your google account?

Comment: At first I assumed you were using Gmail but then you talk about signing into Virgin Media to view email so I'm a little lost as to what you're trying to do. Can you provide a little more detail?